Power-Automate: Azure DevOps connector - when a build completes trigger output "Parameters" is always empty
I am working on a teams notifications automation for my pipeline. I would like to output details of this pipeline to my teams channel when build completes successfully.
Every needed output from AzureDevOps connector works fine (BuildId, Url, SourceBranch,...), except "parameters"

After this flows get triggered I get a message to my teams chat like this one

Right now I am using a basic pipeline that echoes parameter "line"

Here is the run of the pipeline

I am expecting to see parameters of the pipeline in my teams chat. (Am I misunderstanding this output called "Parameters"?)

If you check the run history of the Power Automate workflow, you will find it doesn't contain the pipeline parameter for When a build completes. Hence, you cannot get the parameter in next Post message in a chat or channel action.
After When a build completes, you can add a HTTP action, to get the devops build result, the url like https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buidid}?api-version=6.0. You can get {buildid} from previous When a build completes action. It contains the templatesparameters line in the response. Then you can use it in action Post message in a chat or channel.

This seems like a great idea. Just one more thing. How can I use basic auth using http action to devops. Because right now I am getting a 401 unauthorized error. I want to use PAT to achieve successfull authorization. I can achieve this in postman using its authorization tab. But it doesnt work in power automate (can I skip username in basic auth).

You can Encode the string  to base64, and put in Headers, please refer to the sample screenshot for your reference.

Thanks this helped a lot. Knowing that the send request to devops action doesnt handle authorization correctly allowed me to change this action to a basic HTTP request that handles it like it should. It works now.
